# KVM guest I/O hangs randomly

Tags: linux, kvm

I have a problem with my KVM guest. Sometimes disk read is instant, and sometimes it is terribly slow(23s on below example). Guest is not loaded, CPU, and IO usage is very low. Also Host seems ok, no errors in messages, I checked the disks with SMART, and they are ok. KVM guest is running on qcow2 image so not very fast, but response time 23s is terrible. How can I investigate this ?

[root@med-ganglia ~]# for i in {1..100}; do sleep 1; time less /var/log/messages > /etc/null;done

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.038s
sys 0m0.011s

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.039s
sys 0m0.010s

real    0m0.049s
user    0m0.041s
sys 0m0.009s

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.040s
sys 0m0.009s

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.037s
sys 0m0.012s

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.039s
sys 0m0.009s

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.036s
sys 0m0.012s

real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.040s
sys 0m0.011s

real    0m0.047s
user    0m0.039s
sys 0m0.009s

real    0m0.048s
user    0m0.042s
sys 0m0.007s

real    0m23.581s
user    0m0.039s
sys 0m0.013s

Then only error I found in Host logs: 13 08:51:45 med-master1 libvirtd[1661]: End of file while reading data: Input/output error